# How to create a new model property that combines data from model record

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In AngularJS 1.2, I have a controller that reads JSON data into single records.  Those records (Conference Sessions) each have arrays in them that are the Session Speakers.  That is, something like:

```
data: [{title: 't1',speakers: ['speaker1','speaker2']},...]
```

I want to write some JavaScript that will combine the speakers so that in my ng-repeater I can output them simply.  That is, I want to create a new property in the model that is a comma separated list of speakers.

If I use th ng-repeater, I'm having issues killing the trailing comma and also not having that data in a span or div causing a line break.

Comment: Can you show what your current approach is?

Comment: data.speakerList = data.speakers.join()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to combine the speakers for the view then a filter would be the right choice. There is no combination filter built in, but it's easy to create:

```
module.filter('combine', function() {
  return function(array) {
    return array.join(', ');
  }
});
```

In your view:

```
<p>{{data.speakers | combine}}</p>
```

The output would be:

```
<p>speaker1, speaker2</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly do you want to do something like the following:

```
module.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var data = [
            {title: 't1', speakers: ['speaker1', 'speaker2']}
        ],
        speakers = [];

    angular.forEach(data, function (object, i) {
        speakers = speakers.concat(object.speakers);
    });

    $scope.allSpeakersText = speakers.join(',');
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks Esteban.  I thought of that but as a newbie to Angular, I was wondering if there was a layer closer to the view that does this for me.  Maybe I'm over thinking this.